# Scroll Position ASP.NET hidden elements are not present in Firefox 4

Tags: asp.net, firefox4

We're having a problem with Firefox 4 and javascript that references the SCROLLPOSITION asp.net hidden fields. The are really two problems. First, the following fields don't seem to be present when rendering the page in Firefox 4 (but they are there in IE9, and were presumably there in Firefox 3 since we had no problems then):

```
<div class="aspNetHidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0" />
</div>
```

Second, Firefox 4 allows the javascript error that results from referencing the non-existent scroll position elements to kill all other javascript for the entire page. So, Telerik controls stop working, etc.

Anyway, it looks like the solution is to get the hidden fields to properly show up in Firefox 4 (note: other aspNetHidden fields, such as EVENTTARGET and VIEWSTATE, are showing up properly). Is this a BrowserCaps thing? I thought BrowserCaps was done for (we are using .NET 4). We have no .browser files in the folder structure of the web site.

What could be causing the scroll position fields to not show up in Firefox 4? Thanks.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue, exactly as described here.  Variables are present in other browsers, but not in Firefox 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did turn out to be a browser caps issue. I'm pretty sure that C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers\firefox.browser needed to be modified to affect 4.x in addition to 3.x. It's a stupid problem that will keep biting us every time a new browser comes out, so we are trying to come up with a better solution that doesn't involve playing whack-a-mole with browser files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t care about specifying the correct capabilities on (now) ancient versions of Firefox, it’s pretty simple to enable the “supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback” capability for all future version of Firefox. You can do this on a per-application basis by creating a file (say, “firefox.browser") under the `App_Browsers` folder, with the following contents:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Firefox">
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```